# How to show Woocommerce add to cart form for variable product on custom location

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Woocommerce  wraps the add to cart button inside a form. When the product is a variable product the form contains a drop-down list for product variations.

I am making a custom theme and want to show that form on custom location.
Is it possible to print that form outside the loop/On a custom location in a single product page? If yes then how can I accomplish that?

Comment: So do you think Woocommerce is outside of WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out this.

Adding 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart()' function prints the variable product's add to cart form.